# Organize django apps inside

Tags: django

When creating the apps you do the following: python manage.py startapp app1, but this automatically creates the app inside the root folder of the project.

```
/project1/
         /app1/
         /app2/
         ...
         __init__.py
         manage.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
```

how to create and save in a folder already created all the apps that are created in Django? for example: in this case I have a folder called "apps" inside it I will have all the apps that are created during the development time:

```
/project/
         apps/
              app1/
              app2/
              ...
         __init__.py
         manage.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
```

Anyone who can provide information would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: @Tobin How is it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/django-admin/#startapp),

> `django-admin startapp name [directory]`
>
> Creates a Django application directory structure with the specified
> application name, either in the current directory or in the specified
> destination.

For instance:

```
django-admin startapp myapp apps/myapp
```

Then you will have to slightly modify the settings file so that django recognizes the apps:

```
import os
import sys # new

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
]
...
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps')) # at the bottom of the file
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works in my case. In settings.py

```
import sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# NEW: Add apps directory to Python file path
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
```

Then you can use all the apps in this folder just in the same way as they were in your project root!

```
"app_name.apps.App_nameConfig"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly run `django-admin startproject project_name`
If you want to create in current directory  you can write dot at the end of command like that: `django-admin startproject project_name .`

Then creating app `python manage.py startapp app_name`

Visit for more explanation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Create folder inside project folder and go inside that new created folder

Then run command to create the app (no need to give folder path, as you are already inside your desired folder)

Go to apps.py file inside new created app and change the name. Add the folder name before your appname connecting both with a dot

e.g. folder name is apps and app name is myapp, change name = 'apps.myapp'

Now go to main settings.py and add your app name in same way (apps.myapp)

In main url also, when defining the path you will use folder name before app name connecting both by dot.